# I am unable to implement authentication setup for Dialogflow V2 provided in migration guide for my angular chat bot app?

Tags: angular, authentication, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I am migrating my angular application that is using the DialogFlow API V1 and its query function to chat with my bot to Dialog Flow API v2 and its corresponding detectIntent method. But I am facing issue in the implementing authentication step provided by the official docs [here](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v2-auth-setup?hl=en).
I followed all the steps the docs and I am able to see the value of my token when I run the command

```
gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
```

in my Google cloud SDK shell.

The problem is this:
Currently angular app sends the the http request with header in this format:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': "Bearer " + this.token,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
```

where this.token is my API v1 token. I don't know to change this code into something I want:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': "Bearer " + `$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token),`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
```

How can I achieve this my angular application.

Note:

1. I was successful in getting a response from the detectIntnent method by providing my query in the "Try this API" feature provided by Google. Which means I have correct body for POST request, I just need the correct Header.

Apart form this I have one followup question. Apologies if it seem to be trivial because I am new to Angular and dialog flow:

1. I pushed my angular app to heroku. Does this service account authentication introduced in V2 means I need to install Google Cloud in my heroku instance also.

I checked SO for Angular implementation of service authentication feature but I am unable to find it.

Comment: `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token` is a system command executed on a server/local dev environment only. Angular app is executed inside browser `javascript` environment. So you should retrieve a correct `API Key` or `Service Account` authentication, in another way.

Comment: Thanks Thierry,  Can you point me to correct link/resource from where I can read to implement in my angular application?

Comment: Maybe this may help you: https://hackernoon.com/chatbot-with-angular-5-dialogflow-fdac97fef681

Comment: Sorry Thierry but this is the V1api implementation of Dialog Flow which I already did and it is working. I want the same type of resource where V2 api of Dialog dlow is implemented because its in V2 only dialog flow implemented service authentication instead of client token.

Comment: hi jatin you have to regenerate token each 30 min

Comment: @NikhilSavaliya I am not sure If I understand. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: best way is build rest api for your chatbot , i am using angular and dialogflow also , please try use dialogflow nodejs

Comment: @poppop So you mean to say I need to make a separate backend with nodejs and use dialogflow there to connect to my chat bot that I created in frontend using Angular?

Comment: yep, i think so, i am working on it, i did build back end, just follow intruction dialogflow-nodejs , u gonna get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to implement authentication in the V2 version of Dialog Flow. Basically I was confused on how to achieve it. But on doing some research I found that I need to make a back-end application and use dialog flow package to process the query.
Google has provided a node js [samplecode](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow) to implement v2 version of dialog flow.
This code helped me to make a back-end to handle the query using the detectIntent method.